# Extend helm upgrade cmd to add some field values

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm installing ingress nginx using a modified yaml file

```
kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml
```

The yaml file is just the [original deploy file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml) but with added hostPorts for the deployment:

```
ports:
  - name: http
    containerPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  - name: https
    containerPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
  - name: webhook
    containerPort: 8443
    protocol: TCP
```

become:

```
ports:
  - name: http
    containerPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    hostPort: 80 #<-- added
  - name: https
    containerPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    hostPort: 443 #<-- added
  - name: webhook
    containerPort: 8443
    protocol: TCP
    hostPort: 8443 #<-- added
```

So this is working for me. But I would like to [install](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start) ingress nginx using helm:

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

Is it possible to add the `hostPort` values using helm (`-f values.yml`)? I need to add `hostPort` in `Deployment.spec.template.containers.ports`, but I have two problems to write the correct values.yml file:

*values.yml*

```
# How to access the deployment?
spec:
  template:
    containers:
      ports: # How to add field with existing containerPort value of each element in the array?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to find out:

1. You can take a closer look at the helm chart itself https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx

   Here you can find deployment spec https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml

   And under it, you can see, there's condition that enables `hostPort` https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#L113
2. (Proper one) Always dig through `values.yaml` https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L90

   and chart documentation [https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/README.md#:~:text=controller.hostPort.enabled](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/README.md#:%7E:text=controller.hostPort.enabled)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you already have `hostPort` in *values.yaml*.  See [following fragment](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#:%7E:text=%23%23%20Use%20host%20ports,https%3A%20443):

```yaml
  ## Use host ports 80 and 443
  ## Disabled by default
  hostPort:
    # -- Enable 'hostPort' or not
    enabled: false
    ports:
      # -- 'hostPort' http port
      http: 80
      # -- 'hostPort' https port
      https: 443
```

You should turn it on in *values.yaml*:

```yaml
  ## Use host ports 80 and 443
  ## Disabled by default
  hostPort:
    # -- Enable 'hostPort' or not
    enabled: true
```

After all - as you know - you can install your ingress via `helm`.

```
helm install -f values.yaml
```

About webhook - see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L591).

---

You can find `hostPort` also in deployment file. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml) is one of the templates (*controller-deployment.yaml*):

In this file you can find three appearances of `hostPort` (value `controller.hostPort.enabled` - responsible for enabling or disabling the hostPort).

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#:%7E:text=ports%3A-,%7B%7B%2D%20range%20%24key%2C%20%24value%20%3A%3D%20.Values.controller.containerPort%20%7D%7D,%7B%7B%2D%20end%20%7D%7D,-%7B%7B%2D%20if%20.Values.controller):

```yaml
              {{- if $.Values.controller.hostPort.enabled }}
              hostPort: {{ index $.Values.controller.hostPort.ports $key | default $value }}
              {{- end }}
```

and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#:%7E:text=%7B%7B-%20end%20%7D%7D-,%7B%7B-%20range%20$key,%20$value%20:=%20.Values.tcp%20%7D%7D,%7B%7B-%20end%20%7D%7D,-%7B%7B-%20if%20%28or%20.Values):

```yaml
          {{- range $key, $value := .Values.tcp }}
            - name: {{ $key }}-tcp
              containerPort: {{ $key }}
              protocol: TCP
              {{- if $.Values.controller.hostPort.enabled }}
              hostPort: {{ $key }}
              {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- range $key, $value := .Values.udp }}
            - name: {{ $key }}-udp
              containerPort: {{ $key }}
              protocol: UDP
              {{- if $.Values.controller.hostPort.enabled }}
              hostPort: {{ $key }}
              {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
```

See also:

1. [*ingress-nginx* Documentation on Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/README.md)
2. [*nginx* Documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/)
3. [*NGINX* - Helm Charts](https://github.com/nginxinc/helm-charts)
4. [*Helm* Documentation](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/helm/)

Comment: The hostPort for 8443 is not existing in the values. Only 80 and 443 is working as you described.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the asnwer.